# Another pivot table query

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I am trying to pull three items from a table that have no relation to each other (other than the fact that they are sequential) and get them on one row.

So the table might look like this:

```
time  show
12PM  smallville
1PM   House
2PM   walking dead
```

I know how to get three items based on time but I need the answer to look like this:

```
col1        col2        col3
smallvile   House    walking dead
```

Everything else I have seen is based on some sort of association to each other using multiple columns in the select, I have no such association I just want the three things I select to show up in one row of three columns.

Comment: Solutions to this will vary widely, depending on what DBMS you're using. For instance, what works on SQL Server won't work on MySQL or Oracle, and if you're talking about Excel pivot tables none of the above solutions would work. You need to provide more information.

Comment: usually cosmetics and presentation is a lot easier to do in application code -- in php or python this takes 1-2 lines.

Comment: You can revise my below answer to achieve what you want :) Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

If this question is in relation to SLQ Server and not Excel, then something like the following would be what you're looking for:

```
Select [12PM],[1PM],[2PM],...
from (
 select time, show from tablename
) as sourcetable
PIVOT (
 Max(Show) for Time in [12PM],[1PM],[2PM],...
) as PivotTable
```

See MSDN for further reference on [Pivot Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

Comment: oh. the problem is the "time column" is full of a schedule that will contain the entire days schedule and i need it to pick the current time and the two shows after the current time. so i cant do a select on the time. and sorry yes this is MYsql.  Thanks!

Comment: also, i will be throwing away the time information. the only thing that matters are the show names.

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic [pivot mysql tables](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) (transform rows to columns).

Answer (score 0):

Just put an identity to manipulate the pivot, below code is my sample. Hope it helps.

```
    CREATE TABLE #Temp (ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, [Time] VARCHAR(20), Show VARCHAR(100))

    INSERT INTO #Temp ( [Time] , Show ) 
    SELECT '12PM', 'smallville' UNION SELECT '1PM', 'House' UNION SELECT '2PM', 'walking dead'

    SELECT [1], [2], [3]
        FROM ( 
    SELECT Show, ID FROM #Temp
    ) As src
    PIVOT
        (Max(Show) FOR ID IN ([1], [2], [3])) AS pvt
```

[image]